# Issue with json parsing in D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying the D3 sunburst example and using the JSON at the end of the post below.

When I load the JSON from the text file, it works fine.

```
d3.json("usage.json", function(error, root) {
 var g = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(partition.nodes(root))
.enter().append("g");
```

the `root` object is showing the 3 children objects in the screenshot below.

[image]

However, when I try to get the same object via a WebSocket, the JSON objects returned are not getting parsed properly. I am using `JSON.parse` method to convert the string to JSON object but still, **there is something wrong, please check out the screenshot. I am doing something silly but not sure how to fix it.**

[image]

JSON :

```
{"name":"usage","children":[{"name":"a","children":[
 {"name":"g3","children":[
 {"name":"asof","children":[{"user":"victor","size":84259,"name":"victor"},
 {"user":"james","size":63851,"name":"james"},
 {"user":"john","size":48907,"name":"john"},
 {"user":"larry","size":98758,"name":"larry"}]},
 {"name":"custom","children":[{"user":"victor","size":61579,"name":"victor"},
 {"user":"james","size":68109,"name":"james"}]},
 {"name":"intervalize","children":        [{"user":"victor","size":44107,"name":"victor"},
 {"user":"james","size":29142,"name":"james"}]}]}]}]}
```

Comment: should it be ```var obj```? (otherwise I can't see anything)

Comment: Isn't this a server side issue? Could you show us the code that is used to fetch the json data and what language you are using to do that? Alternatively you could use `.replace()` method to remove all the backslashes

Comment: thanks a lot. I was parsing my objects to JSON twice on the server side. After fixing it I am getting the desired results. Thanks.